Incorrectly registered broadcast receiver in play console quick review
I am getting an issue while pushing my app to the Google Play Console.
Incorrectly registered broadcast receiver
Apps targeting Android 13 or later must specify the export behavior when calling registerReceiver(). Having unspecified export behavior may cause your app to crash.
Your app targets Android 13 or later and registers non-system broadcast receivers without specifying their export behavior in the following places:
Update your app so it specifies the export behavior for registered broadcast receivers.
I have the regiserReceiver is like the below code.
`
     @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
  private fun registerBroadcastReceiver() {
      smsBroadcastReceiver = SmsBroadcastReceiver()
      smsBroadcastReceiver!!.smsBroadcastReceiverListener =
          object : SmsBroadcastReceiver.SmsBroadcastReceiverListener {
              override fun onSuccess(intent: Intent?) {
                  if (intent != null) {
                      startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_USER_CONSENT)
                  }
              }

              override fun onFailure() {}
          }

      val intentFilter = IntentFilter(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION)

      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) {
          // For Android 13 (API 33) and later, explicitly define non-export behavior
          requireContext().registerReceiver(
              smsBroadcastReceiver,
              intentFilter,
              Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED // Explicitly set as non-exported
          )
      } else {
          // Default behavior for older versions
          requireContext().registerReceiver(smsBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter,
              RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
          )
      }
  }

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    registerBroadcastReceiver()
}`

